# Finitely generated ideal in boolean ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

A boolean ring is a commutative ring where $x^{2} = x$ for every $x$.

Why in such a ring a finitely generated ideal is principal ?

Comment: Hi! If you search for your question before you post it, you may find answers right away. Questions like this one have been asked many times before, and we don't like to have more duplicates of the same stuff.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to show this by induction on the number of generators of your ideal.

I'll show this for two generators. If $I=(x,y)$, then certainly $(x+y+xy) \subseteq I$.

Conversely, $x(x+y+xy) = x^2 +xy + x^2y = x+2xy = x \in (x+y+xy)$ (Assuming you've shown that $2x = 0\; \forall \; x$ Similarly, $(x+y+xy)y = y \in (x+y+xy)$ so $(x,y) \subseteq (x+y+xy)$ and we have equality.