# How to test whether an element is in a principal ideal of a ring without enumerating all elements of the ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, monoid, boolean-ring

Suppose we have a finite, boolean ring $A$ induced by a finite, commutative, boolean monoid $X$ containg $0$ as in:
[this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402876/size-of-a-boolean-ring-induced-by-a-finite-commutative-boolean-monoid).  You only need the first few paragraphs of that long post.

Suppose I have a principal ideal $(i) \subset A$ and I want to test whether $u \in (i)$ efficiently.  That is whether or not you can write $u = ri$ for some $r \in A$.  But I can't very well test all posible elements in $r \in A$, so I have to come up with a short cut.

Does math have an answer?

---

Note that every ideal in a boolean ring is principal.  See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/725218/26327) for proof of it.

Comment: “Note that at every ideal in a Boolean ring is principal” That is not true and is not what your reference says.  You omitted the finite generation condition.  I know in your case you are only interested in finite rings but it’s still not good to omit it.

Comment: What is the stuff after “induced by...”  supposed to contribute?  What special subclass of the already very simple class of finite Boolean rings does it single out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any Boolean ring at all, $x\in (y)$ if and only if $xy=x$.  That seems to be amply efficient in your context.

Comment: Yes, intuitively this should work, and it's easy to prove.  Thanks!